# How to create javascript array when each element is a pair of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

hello I would like to build an array that every element will be a pair of objects , Something like this

```
var Shelves = new arr[][]
var books = new Books[] ;
Shelves[book[i],book[j=i+1]],[book[i+1],book[j=i+1]] and so on......;
```

I mean that I understand how to go with a for loop and to get the elements 'but how to push them in pairs array?    `arr.push`    doesn't work :(

```
build1ArrPairs(1Arr) {
    if (1Arr != undefined || 1Arr!=null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1Arr.length; i = i + 1) {
            for (var j = i + 1; j <= 1Arr.length; j++) {
                this.1ArrPair.push(1Arr[i] 1Arr[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you give an example of your required output array?

Comment: If you need an Array of Arrays, you can try pushing array in to an array, e.g. `this.1ArrPair.push([1Arr[i], 1Arr[j]]);`

Comment: give an example,input:,,,,,,output:,,,,,,

Comment: You have an immediate call to `break` inside the inner loop. Is that on purpose?

Comment: GalAbra yes it is on purpose, it's like I have 10 books and I want 2 books on each shelve 'so I take the first one and the second put them on first shelve and go back to all books.

Comment: can't you just use a spread operator to combine 2 arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `array#reduce` to group your array.

```js
var names = ['a', 'b','c','d','e'];
var result = names.reduce((r,w,i) => {
  let index = Math.floor(i/2);
  if(!Array.isArray(r[index]))
    r[index] = [];
  r[index].push(w);
  return r;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I found some thing similar ... I just creat an object that contains a pair. And then push it to my array. The 'for' loop jumps i+2, inside the loop I check if index is odd , cause I only in that case I create  a pair object , otherwise I go to next Index . In the end i check if the index is the last one and push it into array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, variables names can't start with a number.

Second, initialize an array, then add your elements - two at a time - and return the array:

```
var ans = [];
if (Arr != undefined || Arr != null) {
    for (var i=0; i<(Arr.length-1); i+=2) { // Note the loop stops 2 elements before the last one
        ans.push([Arr[i], Arr[i+1]]);
    //                  ^ Note the comma - it's missing in your code
    }
}
return ans;
```

Comment: Hi, I have to use two 'for' loops because I don't want the same object appears  in two pairs. And how you can add 2 objects in array with single level? I need arr [obj,obj]... something like this

Comment: @user3035279 That's easy - just set the `for` loop to increment by 2 after each iteration. I've edited my code. You can see in my code why you don't need the nested loop

Comment: You also need to think what you want to do with the last element, if the number of books is odd. Currently the last element in an odd array is just ommitted

Comment: How to create array that every element is a pair of objects? it will look like var arr = new Array<T>[][]? or what?

Comment: @user3035279 I just showed you in my answer. The argument of `push` should be a pair

Comment: Hey @user3035279, every entity in an array must be of a valid JavaScript type, "a pair of objects" doesn't exist in JS. Its either an `array` or an `object`

Comment: @surajck That's an important clarification! Thank you